# css/jquery - extract all element margin values into one variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there a short hand way of doing this series of jquery below to extract every margin value.

```
var x = jQuery('#widget-container').css('margin-top');
var y = jQuery('#widget-container').css('margin-bottom');
var z = jQuery('#widget-container').css('margin-right');
var a = jQuery('#widget-container').css('margin-left');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `margin` css directly to get `top, right, bottom and left` margin respectively.

```
var margin = jQuery("#widget-container").css("margin");
alert(margin);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLdk/2/)**

**Edit** : Above jQuery may or may not work in firefox because if css property (margin in this case) not set in the css of element explicitly, it does not support shorthand css for that property.
To achieve the same in firefox, we can do following workaround :

```
var marginArray = ['Top','Right','Bottom','Left'];

for(var i=0;i<marginArray.length;i++)
{
    alert(jQuery("#widget-container").css("margin"+marginArray[i]));
}
```

**[JSFiddle for Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLdk/7/)**

Comment: It does not work when each margin is set separately.

Comment: have you check my jsfiddle?

Comment: I see it. it does not display any margin value.

Comment: It displays '10px 30px 40px 20px' .. which browser you are using. And as @AnoopJoshi said can you share a fiddle which does not work with seperate margin?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Think if you have whole margin values how would you allot it to specific varialbles.

Comment: @Jai, we can split it by space and use it as per top, right, bottom and left order

Comment: @Juhana, Yes I do agree with you.

Comment: The answer is correct, but the explanation isn't: Firefox does support CSS shorthand properties. They're just not necessarily always available from JavaScript if they're not explicitly set in CSS.

Comment: @Juhana, updated my explanation. please have a look. I appreciate your support. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this,

```
var =$("#widget-container").css("margin").split(" ");
```

The return value will be in the following order: `top, right, bottom, left` in an array.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubBSp/5/)

Comment: It does not work when each margin is set separately.

Comment: @jacelysh did you even check the fiddle?

Comment: It only returns value when shorthand "margin" is used.

Comment: @jacelysh Can you create a fiddle which has the proof of "It does not work when each margin is set separately"

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work on all browsers. From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/css/): *"Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background, border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed."* And even in browsers that support it, it might return the two-value shorthand. Try with Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ubBSp/7/

Comment: @Juhana So you are saying that, there is no possible way to getting the margin css using jquery?

Comment: I checked your fiddle, even if i used 'margin-top' there it will return 16 px. http://jsfiddle.net/ubBSp/8/

Comment: I'm not saying that. I'm saying that you can't do it with `.css('margin')`.